# Get the variable declared in asp page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

I have this variable x. it contain the ID that i need to use to insert into another table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         int x = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

         // Create Connection
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
         // Create Command
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.Connection = con;
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, FROM Hardware WHERE ID = " + x;
         //Create DataReader
         SqlDataReader reader;
         con.Open();
         reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         dlstDetails.DataSource = reader;
         dlstDetails.DataBind();
     }
 }
```

I want to access it here:

```
protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get x    
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Before you do anything else you should read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: If you want to access a query string value you would access it exactly like you did in Page_Load. When you declare your variable inside a method they are visible only to that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web is stateless and you can either pull it from your query string `Request.QueryString["id"]` or use `Session` like this:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
Session["X"] = x;
```

And then:

```
protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( Session["X"] != null)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Session["X"].ToString());
    }
 }
```

Also you should be aware that this kind of codes are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: I would probably just pull it from the query string again instead of using the session.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes. Thanks. I mentioned it also in my answer.